# strange behaviour using sizeof in C++

Tags: c++, sizeof

I'm very new to C++. From examples, I find this use of `sizeof` in order to retrieve the length of an array

```
int main()
{
int newdens[10];
// the first line returns 10 which is correct
std::cout << "\nLength of array = " << (sizeof(v1)/sizeof(*v1)) << std::endl;
std::cout << "\nLength of array = " << (sizeof(v1) << std::endl; //returns 40
std::cout << "\nLength of array = " << (sizeof(*v1)) << std::endl; //returns 4
    }
```

But if i wrote a function like this

```
#include <iostream>

void myCounter(int v1[])
    {
    int L, L2, L3;
    L = (sizeof(v1)/sizeof(*v1)); 
    L2 = (sizeof(v1)); 
    L3 = (sizeof(*v1)); 
    std::cout << "\nLength of array = " << L << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nLength of array = " << L2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nLength of array = " << L3 << std::endl;

    }

int main()
{
int v1[10];

std::cout << "\nLength of array = " << (sizeof(v1)/sizeof(*v1)) << std::endl;
std::cout << "\nLength of array = " << (sizeof(v1)) << std::endl;
std::cout << "\nLength of array = " << (sizeof(*v1)) << std::endl;

myCounter(v1);
    }
```

the outputs are L=2, L2 = 8, L3 = 4. I can't understand where the problem is.

How to retrieve the correct lenght of v1 inside the function?

Comment: in `void myCounter(int v1[])`, `v1` has decayed to a pointer. All of its array-ness has been stripped away, so it no longer knows its length.

Comment: and sizeof(pointer) == 8 (generally), sizeof(int) == 4, so do the math...

Comment: you should take a look at `std::vector` which has a `size` method

Comment: Other handy reading: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) First answer explains quite well and gives a few avoidance techniques (which you may or may not be able to use).

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for directing me to a solution

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that `sizeof()` is resolved at compile time. As it has no information about how large is your array, it cannot tell its size. It interprets it as a pointer to an int, which is 64-bit on your machine.

The best way for you is to use std::vector instead of C-style array and use its method `size()`.

Comment: `sizeof` most definitely gives you the size of an array.  The issues is in the function you no longer have an array.

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't know that actually!

Comment: Recommend an update to the answer to take that into account. No point leaving it mostly correct when it can be all correct. In addition, an answer should give a solution to the problem where possible.

Comment: The answer has been edited along your advice.